# Search query doesn't return @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

It seems that the Microsoft Graph search functionality for `driveItem` doesn't return a `@mcirosoft.graph.downloadUrl`

Using the Graph Explorer, I tried to fetch the following and the `downloadUrl` isn't present in the response:

```html
/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='')?$select=id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
```

In the documentation, the `DriveItem` should include the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` on the response.

Answer (score 2):

The `select` query parameter applies only to [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), not [instance attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). Instance attributes are properties with special behaviors.

In your query, `id,name,file,folder,size,lastModifiedDateTime` are valid properties but `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` is an instance attribute.

In order to obtain the `downloadUrl`, you will need to execute a second call to `/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items{driveItemId}`.